# Graphs Table Sonar Qube Database

Tags: mysql, graph, sonarqube

After running a sonarqube analysis for a project with 1.8 million lines of code for a few times. I got the error message.

> 'graphs' table is full.

I deleted the table manually and afterwards it worked again.

Is there a way to avoid deleting the 'graphs' table from time to time?

Comment: Do you heavily use tracking of test coverage in Java projects thanks to JaCoCo ?

Comment: Yes I'm using JaCoCo for the test coverage in Java for the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is expected. Tracking of test coverage stores all the relations between source code and tests. Number of relations, so size of table GRAPHS, is exponential if tests are more "integration" tests (involving more than one class) than "unit". That's probably your case. The solution is to simply disable the feature.

See section "coverage per test" here: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/JaCoCo+Plugin. The JUnit listener org.sonar.java.jacoco.JUnitListener must be disabled when executing JUnit. For example in Maven projects: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/projects/languages/java/code-coverage/ut/ut-maven-jacoco/pom.xml#L42

Comment: I'm only using unit test coverage and no integration coverage. Which feature do you recommend to disable? The coverage feature? I my case it is one of the central metrics in sonarqube. Disabling coverage feature is normaly no opportunity.

Comment: No. There are two features: test coverage (the percent value) and what we name "tracking of test coverage" (list of the tests that cover a given line of code). Of course the test coverage measure is central and must be kept. I was talking about the second one, which consumes of lot of space if the unit tests are "badly" designed (that's what I name the "integration test way": a test covers a lot of classes).

Comment: Ok I understand. But how can I disable this feature?  I use the plugin "sonar-generic-coverage-plugin-1.1".  Can't find any option to disable the "tracking feature".

Comment: You said that you use JaCoCo for Java projects, not the generic coverage plugin. Can you clarify please ?

Comment: Ok it was my mistake. I use the JaCoCo for Java projects. http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project

Comment: I quote my answer: "The JUnit listener org.sonar.java.jacoco.JUnitListener must be disabled when executing JUnit."